# Handle large delimited text files in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Using VBA, I need to "unpivot" data that is currently in delimited text files (as hundreds of columns by tens of thousands of rows) into a normalized form (four columns by millions of rows); that is, the resulting table will comprise columns that, for each cell:

- identify the original table/file;
- identify the cell's row in the original table;
- identify the cell's column in the original table;
- contain the value of that cell.

I would generally be grateful for any thoughts on how one can efficiently accomplish this task.

So far, I have considered using ADODB to construct a `SELECT INTO ... UNION ...` query that builds the output table, but the default text file providers are sadly limited to 255 columns (are there any which aren't?).

Sébastien Lorion has built a terrific [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), which I would love to use, but I do not know how to use it from within VBA - grateful for any thoughts (I don't think it has been compiled to export COM interfaces, and I don't have the tools to recompile it).  For that matter, Microsoft also provide a [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class, but again I do not know if/how this can be used from VBA.

Another approach might be to have Excel >=2007 open the source file and construct the output table from there, but that intuitively 'feels' as though it will incur considerable wasted overhead...

Comment: How often do you need to do it (once? several times?)? What is the maximum time the task can take to complete? What is the size of the files (MB)?

Comment: @assylias: The task will be performed once per input file, but new input files (with different columns!) will arise from time to time - their data must be appended to the same aggregate output table; hard to quantify how long the task should take, but it should appear quite responsive to an interactive user - so let's say no more than 20 seconds?; the files are of the order of 10MB.

Comment: What part of this has you stumped? Is it just parsing each line from a CSV file into an array of values?

Comment: Are you identifying columns by position, or by a header value?

Comment: @TimWilliams: By a header value (given in the first row); the bit that has me stumped is how to do use an existing library rather than attempt reinventing the wheel.  Isn't that just plain old good practise?

Comment: In general that's always good practice yes, but in this particular case you seem to have some problem finding a suitable one, so folk (myself included) have offered approaches which should - maybe with some tweaking - work for you. To be honest if you really want to use a "tested" approach you should just use Excel to open the files and reformat the worksheet content into the new file.

Comment: @TimWilliams: I don't agree that I "have some problem finding a suitable [library]" - I'm just having some problems understanding how to use those libraries within VBA!  I'm fairly sure that it's possible (given answers to similar questions on this site), but I could do with a little help in making it work.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to build a tiny COM-aware wrapper around `TextFieldParser` in VB.NET.  Not ideal, but the best I can come up with at present.

Comment: Do, please, post the code for that. It's unusual to encounter csv files with more than 255 columns, but most developers will get it once.

Answer (score 2):

Compiled but not tested

```
Sub UnpivotFile(sPath As String)

    Const DELIM As String = ","
    Const QUOTE As String = """"

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim arrHeader
    Dim arrContent
    Dim lb As Integer, ub As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim inData As Boolean
    Dim l As String, fName As String
    Dim fIn As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim fOut As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim lineNum As Long

    fName = FSO.GetFileName(sPath)

    Set fIn = FSO.OpenTextFile(sPath, ForReading)
    Set fOut = FSO.OpenTextFile(sPath & "_out", ForWriting)
    lineNum = 0

    Do While Not fIn.AtEndOfStream

        l = fIn.ReadLine
        lineNum = lineNum + 1
        arrContent = ParseLineToArray(l, DELIM, QUOTE)

        If Not inData Then
            arrHeader = arrContent
            lb = LBound(arrHeader)
            ub = UBound(arrHeader)
            inData = True
        Else
            For x = lb To ub
                fOut.WriteLine Join(Array(fName, lineNum, _
                               QID(arrHeader(x), DELIM, QUOTE), _
                               QID(arrContent(x), DELIM, QUOTE)), DELIM)

            Next x
        End If
    Loop
    fIn.Close
    fOut.Close
End Sub

'quote if delimiter found
Function QID(s, d As String, q As String)
    QID = IIf(InStr(s, d) > -1, q & s & q, s)
End Function


'Split a string into an array based on a Delimiter and a Text Identifier
Private Function ParseLineToArray(sInput As String, m_Delim As String, _
                                  m_TextIdentifier As String) As Variant
   'Dim vArr As Variant
   Dim sArr() As String
   Dim bInText As Boolean
   Dim i As Long, n As Long
   Dim sTemp As String, tmp As String

   If sInput = "" Or InStr(1, sInput, m_Delim) = 0 Then
      'zero length string, or delimiter not present
      'dump all input into single-element array (minus Text Identifier)
      ReDim sArr(0)
      sArr(0) = Replace(sInput, m_TextIdentifier, "")
      ParseLineToArray = sArr()
   Else
      If InStr(1, sInput, m_TextIdentifier) = 0 Then
         'no text identifier so just split and return
         sArr() = Split(sInput, m_Delim)
         ParseLineToArray = sArr()
      Else
         'found the text identifier, so do it the long way
         bInText = False
         sTemp = ""
         n = 0

         For i = 1 To Len(sInput)
            tmp = Mid(sInput, i, 1)
            If tmp = m_TextIdentifier Then
               'just toggle the flag - don't add to string
               bInText = Not bInText
            Else
               If tmp = m_Delim Then
                  If Not bInText Then
                     'delimiter not within quoted text, so add next array member
                     ReDim Preserve sArr(n)
                     sArr(n) = sTemp
                     sTemp = ""
                     n = n + 1
                  Else
                     sTemp = sTemp & tmp
                  End If
               Else
                  sTemp = sTemp & tmp
               End If           'character is a delimiter
            End If              'character is a quote marker
         Next i

         ReDim Preserve sArr(n)
         sArr(n) = sTemp

         ParseLineToArray = sArr()
      End If 'has any quoted text
   End If 'parseable

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim - but my aversion to building my own parser remains: why reinvent the wheel and suffer pitfalls others have already overcome?  For example, I don't think your solution handles quoted row delimiters... libraries have been written, tested, and widely deployed for reading/writing delimited text files - surely there's a way one can use them from VBA?!

Comment: What's a quoted row delimiter?  Are you expecting rows to be delimited by something other than a newline sequence (\n,\n\r\ or \r) ?

Comment: What happens when (\n, \n\r or \r) occur within "..."?  In most delimited text formats I've come across (and certainly within that used in this application), those characters should be treated as part of the value of the field in quotes and not as a row delimiter.  Furthermore, I think your approach does not properly handle text identifier marks that are contained within a field... fair enough I can tweak these issues, but what about other edge cases I've not considered?  Edge cases other people have already encountered and solved in thoroughly tested libraries.

Comment: Agreed - it's a big hassle to handle all those cases. If you have to be able to deal with those then just opening them in Excel 2007+ seems the obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fast enough (it takes 8 secs on a 18MB file on my machine, but I only copy data, I don't restructure it - if you don't do calculations but only reorder stuff you should get the same kind of performance). It works even if the number of rows / columns would not fit in a spreadsheet.

**TODO**: it is a bit long but you should be able to (a) copy paste it (b) change the file names and (c) amend the manipulateData function to suit your needs. The rest of the code is a bunch of reusable utilities functions that you should not need to change.

I am not sure you can get much faster using VBA - if you need faster, you should consider an alternative language. Typically, the same code in Java or C# would much shorter because they already have standard libraries to read / write files etc. and would be faster too.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub doIt()
    Dim sourceFile As String
    Dim destinationFile As String
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim result As Variant

    sourceFile = "xxxxxxx"
    destinationFile = "xxxxxxx"

    data = getDataFromFile(sourceFile, ",")
    If Not isArrayEmpty(data) Then
       result = manipulateData(data)
       writeToCsv result, destinationFile, ","
    Else
       MsgBox ("Empty file")
    End If
End Sub

Function manipulateData(sourceData As Variant) As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim m As Long

    'redim the result array to the right size - here I only copy so same size as source
    ReDim result(1 To UBound(sourceData, 1), 1 To UBound(sourceData, 2)) As Variant

    For i = LBound(sourceData, 1) To UBound(sourceData, 1)
        For j = LBound(sourceData, 2) To UBound(sourceData, 2)
            k = i 'k to be defined - here I only copy data
            m = j 'm to be defined - here I only copy data
            result(k, m) = sourceData(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    manipulateData = result
End Function

Public Sub writeToCsv(parData As Variant, parFileName As String, parDelimiter As String)

    If getArrayNumberOfDimensions(parData) <> 2 Then Exit Sub

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim fileNum As Long
    Dim locLine As String
    Dim locCsvString As String

    fileNum = FreeFile
    If Dir(parFileName) <> "" Then Kill (parFileName)
    Open parFileName For Binary Lock Read Write As #fileNum

    For i = LBound(parData, 1) To UBound(parData, 1)
      locLine = ""
      For j = LBound(parData, 2) To UBound(parData, 2)
        If IsError(parData(i, j)) Then
          locLine = locLine & "#N/A" & parDelimiter
        Else
          locLine = locLine & parData(i, j) & parDelimiter
        End If
      Next j
      locLine = Left(locLine, Len(locLine) - 1)
      If i <> UBound(parData, 1) Then locLine = locLine & vbCrLf
      Put #fileNum, , locLine
    Next i

error_handler:
    Close #fileNum

End Sub

Public Function isArrayEmpty(parArray As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns false if not an array or dynamic array that has not been initialised (ReDim) or has been erased (Erase)

  If IsArray(parArray) = False Then isArrayEmpty = True
  On Error Resume Next
  If UBound(parArray) < LBound(parArray) Then isArrayEmpty = True: Exit Function Else: isArrayEmpty = False

End Function

Public Function getArrayNumberOfDimensions(parArray As Variant) As Long
'Returns the number of dimension of an array - 0 for an empty array.

    Dim i As Long
    Dim errorCheck As Long

    If isArrayEmpty(parArray) Then Exit Function 'returns 0

    On Error GoTo FinalDimension
    'Visual Basic for Applications arrays can have up to 60000 dimensions
    For i = 1 To 60001
        errorCheck = LBound(parArray, i)
    Next i

    'Not supposed to happen
    getArrayNumberOfDimensions = 0
    Exit Function

FinalDimension:
    getArrayNumberOfDimensions = i - 1

End Function

Private Function getDataFromFile(parFileName As String, parDelimiter As String, Optional parExcludeCharacter As String = "") As Variant
'parFileName is supposed to be a delimited file (csv...)
'parDelimiter is the delimiter, "," for example in a comma delimited file
'Returns an empty array if file is empty or can't be opened
'number of columns based on the line with the largest number of columns, not on the first line
'parExcludeCharacter: sometimes csv files have quotes around strings: "XXX" - if parExcludeCharacter = """" then removes the quotes


  Dim locLinesList() As Variant
  Dim locData As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim locNumRows As Long
  Dim locNumCols As Long
  Dim fso As Variant
  Dim ts As Variant
  Const REDIM_STEP = 10000

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  On Error GoTo error_open_file
  Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
  On Error GoTo unhandled_error

  'Counts the number of lines and the largest number of columns
  ReDim locLinesList(1 To 1) As Variant
  i = 0
  Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    If i Mod REDIM_STEP = 0 Then
      ReDim Preserve locLinesList(1 To UBound(locLinesList, 1) + REDIM_STEP) As Variant
    End If
    locLinesList(i + 1) = Split(ts.ReadLine, parDelimiter)
    j = UBound(locLinesList(i + 1), 1) 'number of columns
    If locNumCols < j Then locNumCols = j
    If j = 13 Then
      j = j
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop

  ts.Close

  locNumRows = i

  If locNumRows = 0 Then Exit Function 'Empty file

  ReDim locData(1 To locNumRows, 1 To locNumCols + 1) As Variant

  'Copies the file into an array
  If parExcludeCharacter <> "" Then

    For i = 1 To locNumRows
      For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
        If Left(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          If Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
            locLinesList(i)(j) = Mid(locLinesList(i)(j), 2, Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 2)       'If locTempArray = "", Mid returns ""
          Else
            locLinesList(i)(j) = Right(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
          End If
        ElseIf Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          locLinesList(i)(j) = Left(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
        End If
        locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
      Next j
    Next i

  Else

    For i = 1 To locNumRows
      For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
        locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
      Next j
    Next i

  End If

  getDataFromFile = locData

  Exit Function

error_open_file:                 'returns empty variant
unhandled_error:                 'returns empty variant

End Function
```

Comment: Gosh.  Whilst I appreciate the effort you have gone to in order to implement your own parser, I don't think this is a particularly great solution.  For one thing, fields might be enclosed in quotation marks to escape uses of field/row delimiters.. for another, you're loading the entire file into memory (which doesn't seem especially necessary for my purposes); in general I'd rather rely on existing, tested, supported libraries than attempt reinventing the wheel with all the pitfalls that entails!  Still, thank you anyway.

Comment: @eggyal I understand your point. FWIW the code has been used in production for a while without any issues. Now it has been used in specific conditions and if you have different conditions (like quotes with commas inside) it might not do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used CSV Reader in the past to parse huge CSV files (up to 1 GB). The performance and simplicity is incredible. I highly suggest that you use it.

Since you say you used VB.NET, I suggest that you build a simple console application that references CSV Reader. This console application would take as a command line argument the path to a csv file to "unpivot". Then, from VBA, you could use VBA.Shell to run your console application and give it the path to the CSV file as an argument.