# How to read number of rows and columns in a CSV file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have more than 100 CSV/text files (vary in size between 1MB to 1GB). I Just need to create a excel sheet for each csv file, presenting:

- name of columns
- types of column i.e. numeric or string
- number of records in each column
- min & max values & length of each column

so the output on a sheet would be something like this (I can not paste table image here as I am new on this site, so please consider below dummy table as excel sheet):

```
         A           B         C             D           E          F           G

1   Column_name    Type     #records     min_value   max_value  min_length  max_length
2   Name           string   123456       Alis        Zomby          4         30
3   Age            numeric  123456       10          80             2          2
```

Is is possible to create any vba code for this? I am at very beginner stage so if any expert can help me out on code side, would be really helpful.
thanks!!!

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Instead we are here to help solve specific problems encountered during programming.

Comment: yeah I understand EWit and thanks for your comment, but I just wanted a little guidance to automate this process (if possible) from experts like you guys.

Comment: I can see EWit's point StackOverflow is great for sharing nifty coding tricks and techniques that solve specific problems: but this question takes you into several separate areas of new knowledge, each of them requiring a long and complicated series of explanations from first principles. I'll drop in an answer that a more experienced developer can use, when you get around to asking someone to write the code for this task.

Comment: Have a look e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821013/handle-large-delimited-text-files-in-vba/9821638#9821638 HTH

Comment: Have you tried `Workbooks.Open()` directly? Please post any code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You could try writing complex VBA file- and string-handling code for this; my advice is: don't.

A better approach is to ask: **"What other tools can read a csv file?"**

This is tabulated data, and the files are quite large. Larger, really, than you should be reading using a spreadsheet: it's database work, and your best toolkit will be SQL queries with MIN() MAX() and COUNT() functions to aggregate the data.

Microsoft Access has a good set of 'external data' tools that will read fixed-width files, and if you use 'linked data' rather than 'import table' you'll be able to read the files using SQL queries without importing all those gigabytes into an Access .mdb or .accdb file.

Outside MS-Access, you're looking at intermediate-to-advanced VBA using the ADODB database objects (Microsoft Active-X Data Objects) and a schema.ini file.

Your link  for text file schema.ini files is here:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
```

...And you'll then be left with the work of creating an ADODB database 'connection' object that sees text files in a folder as 'tables', and writing code to scan the file names and build the SQL queries. All fairly straightforward for an experienced developer who's used the ADO text file driver.

I can't offer anything more concrete than these general hints - and nothing like a code sample - because this is quite a complex task, and it's not really an Excel-VBA task; it's a programming task best undertaken with database tools, except for the very last step of displaying your results in a spreadsheet.

This is not a task I'd give a beginner as a teaching exercise, it demands so many unfamiliar concepts and techniques that they'd get nowhere until it was broken down  into a structured series of separate tutorials.

Comment: Putting this into Access is a good idea. While VBA in Excel can do it, it'll be a bit tedious. Are you open to this approach?

Comment: I am ready to go step by step for this tedious job. please suggest